# C# TCPListener stops listening after idle phase

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp, server, listener

I'm trying to figure out why my clients **sometimes** cannot connect to the Server after the listener was running some time without any client tried to connect. 
The only way to fix it, is to restart the TCP listener - the server.
There are no issues if I start the server and some people connect, do stuff and disconnect later.

I have a simple while loop to accept the incoming socket connections:

```
            while (IsOn)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!tcpListener.Pending())
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                        continue;
                    }
                    Socket socket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
                    if (socket != null)
                    {
                        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
                        client.Client = socket;
                        IncommingClientConnection(client); // Nonblocking Code
                    }
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    NetLog.Exception(e, "An error occured while user connected!");
                }
            }
```

The last time the error occured was after around 8 hours of idle time. Sometimes it happens earlier.

I tried to debug this issue but the listener thread was still running and it seems like it hangs on

> tcpListener.AcceptSocket()

.

I've read that this could be fixed by setting up a Windows Service but this would be a lot of work for now. But isn't there any other way to force the Listener to stay opened?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I can't say that I've ever seen this, but... as a pragmatic hack, maybe you could have a timer that (once a minute or so) attempts to connect and disconnect via a socket; if it fails, tear down the listener and recreate it? note: resetting the listener shouldn't upset existing established clients - all the listener does is *accept* clients

Comment: Do you have proper disposing of your client in IncommingClientConnection(client) after using it?

Comment: Is it possible that incoming requests are being processed in the same thread they're being received in? Then a new request won't be accepted until the previous one is processed. If there're any issues with the request processing, some clients may experience problems when trying to connect. AFAIU processing of a request is usually delegated to another thread to make sure any (reasonable) number of clients can connect. Note: have you tried putting a breakpoint after the `AcceptSocket()` line? This command is where your code is waiting for inbound requests hence the seeming hang up.

Comment: FWIW, I think this code will be more efficient without the `Pending` check and the sleep.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error Thanks for this hint. I dont care about 100ms sleep because the incoming clients will stack and processed all at once. After 1(of say 10) clients is connected, the "Pending()" function will return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the error was. It is so ridiculous because why should a freezed thread has something to do with "Console.WriteLine()"?!

The Problem was, that the Console Window on Windows Server 2016 somehow changes to input mode. The thread then blocks on "Console.WriteLine" and waits for the user to press Enter on Console Window?! I tried some scenarios. Even If I did not touch the Remove-Desktop for some time this issue occured.

Solution: Switch from Console Application to Windows Application and track output in the integrated Console-View of your IDE.

I hope this helps someone...